# How to run exe file from docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, console, dockerfile

I am trying to run the exe CLI tool from the docker container.

It does not show any output.
The exe CLI tool must download the file. The file is also missing

```
./AIH.CLI.ConsoleApp.exe dataupload download $fileId -o $fileName
```

like normal it must be

```
File downloaded successfully
```

[but in docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpKLR.png)

```
root@84bc4f03c668:/app/CLI#
root@84bc4f03c668:/app/CLI# ls
AIH.CLI.Application.DesignationV1.pdb  AIH.CLI.ConsoleApp.exe  AIH.CLI.DesignationV2.pdb   config.json
AIH.CLI.Application.pdb                AIH.CLI.ConsoleApp.pdb  AIH.CLI.Infrastructure.pdb
AIH.CLI.Assets.pdb                     AIH.CLI.DataUpload.pdb  AIH.CLI.Signals.pdb
root@84bc4f03c668:/app/CLI# ./AIH.CLI.ConsoleApp.exe dataupload download be5f496a-1fd4-45c0-919b-e42de0d39aa0 -o be5f496a-1fd4-45c0-919b-e42de0d39aa0.xlsx
root@84bc4f03c668:/app/CLI# ls
AIH.CLI.Application.DesignationV1.pdb  AIH.CLI.ConsoleApp.exe  AIH.CLI.DesignationV2.pdb   config.json
AIH.CLI.Application.pdb                AIH.CLI.ConsoleApp.pdb  AIH.CLI.Infrastructure.pdb
AIH.CLI.Assets.pdb                     AIH.CLI.DataUpload.pdb  AIH.CLI.Signals.pdb
```

Comment: Without knowing what the code in the CLI is doing, there's no way to diagnose this.

Comment: It is downloading a file from API and saving it in a system                                                      var fileResponse = await dataUploadClient.FilesDownloadAsync(fileGuid);

            using (var fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                fileResponse.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }